# Azure AD Guest Account SAML Authentication all users

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2b

I am trying to authenticate all guest users in my Azure tenant using my on-prem SAML gateway since I need to share authentication between some on-prem applications and azure and wondering if I can set all guest users to be SAML authenticated.  I see you can do by domain (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation) but some of my users will be gmail and other public / partner domains (not specific).  So, my question is, in the domain, can I use a wildcard or basically say all guest accounts in Azure are federated against a single SAML endpoint for authentication.

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0):

You can surely authenticate all the guest users in your Azure AD by redirecting their authentication request to on-premises applications by using Application Proxy.

You can quickly make your on-premises apps available to your Azure AD B2B collaboration users through the Azure portal if your on premises app uses SAML-based authentication.

To do this need to [**`Enable Application Proxy and install a connector`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-add-on-premises-application).
Then Publish the on-premises SAML-based application through Azure AD Application Proxy. To publish you can refer this [**`MS DOC`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-configure-single-sign-on-on-premises-apps)

For your Azure AD B2B guest users to be able to authenticate to your on-premises applications using SAML-endpoint you will need to ensure that the application is able to perform user access checks and grant access to correct resources as well as publish the on-premises app through the azure ad  application proxy.

For more information please refer this **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**| [***Grant B2B users in Azure AD access to your on-premises applications***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/hybrid-cloud-to-on-premises).